# How to Convert an Array of SwiftyJSON objects to a SwiftyJSON object?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I have :-

```
var myArray:Array = array<JSON>
```

I want :-

```
var myJSON:JSON = myArray as? JSON
```

but i get a warning:-
**Cast from 'Array' to unrelated type 'JSON' always fails**

Can anyone help me how to convert an Array object to a JSON object?

A little more insight what i am trying to do:-
(This might not be needed to answer my above question but still...) Note:- I am using objectMapper for mapping swiftyJSONObjects.

```
var monthArray = Array<JSON>
var allEventsInDayArray:Array<JSON> = [] // an empty array
        for (_,dayObj) in monthArray
        {
            guard let dayEventsArray = dayObj["events"].array else { break   }

        allEventsInDayArray.appendContentsOf(dayEventsArray)
    }

    print(allEventsInDayArray)
    var allEventsJSON:JSON? = JSON(allEventsInDayArray)
    var EventModelArray:Array<EventModel>? = Mapper<EventModel>().mapArray(allEventsJSON?.object.allValues)
```

Comment: You can't make an orange into an apple just with downcasting. Please explain what you want to achieve - maybe there's a better way to do it... ;)

Comment: i agree @Eric D. i Just want an apple can you tell me how can i get it. I dont have an orange but an array of apples ;) Forget about downcasting, i just want to convert an array of Swifty JSON Objects to a SwiftyJSON object.

Comment: Hehe, thanks for answering. :) So indeed we don't care about downcasting here. Unfortunately I don't see how to do this. I will answer if I find out. // May I ask *why* you want this, though? Maybe you have an X/Y problem that could be resolved in a different way, that's also what I meant earlier.

Comment: Sure @EricD. Please see my edited question above

Comment: Well actually @lorenzoliveto's answer is correct, SwiftyJSON is able to transform a Swift array of SwiftyJSON objects to a SwiftyJSON object, I just tried [in a Playground](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOw8CGGPFo9JV48s3d5Ze4PLmBuQdaxfn6o). Good to know.

Comment: This's the code it's calling: `init(_ jsonArray:[JSON])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question and you want to create a SwiftyJSON object from an array you should do like this:

```
var myJSON:JSON = JSON(myArray)
```